# Count matching instances between two data frames

Tags: r

I'm a newbie with R and can't find my answer/anything that works.
I've got two data frames that look like..

```
Teams
A
B
C
...
```

and

```
TCF
A
B
C
C
B
A
...
```

I need to count the number of instances that each of the first DF column occurs in the second DF and return the value to the first DF. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Frank you may improve your thread by giving an account of what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `base R` to do this:

```
  sapply(unique(df1$Teams), function(x) sum(df2$TCF %in% x))
   #A B C 
  #2 2 2
```

Or

```
  setNames(table(match(df2$TCF, unique(df1$Teams))), unique(df1$Teams))

  #A B C 
  #2 2 2
```

Or  using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(df1), Teams)
 setkey(setDT(df2), TCF)
 df2[J(unique(df1$Teams)),.N, by=.EACHI]
 #    TCF N
 #1:   A 2
 #2:   B 2
 #3:   C 2
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Teams = c("A", "B", "C")), .Names = "Teams", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))


 df2 <- structure(list(TCF = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A")), .Names = "TCF", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this option be easier to your eyes?

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% count(TCF) %>% filter(TCF %in% unique(df1$Teams))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#   TCF n
# 1   A 2
# 2   B 2
# 3   C 2
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Teams = c("A", "B", "C")), .Names = "Teams", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
df2 <- structure(list(TCF = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = "TCF", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```